# Customize slack reminder message with today's date

Tags: slack

I was looking at reminders in Slack and they are great. I am able to successfully set a weekday reminder with a particular message. However, I would like to add today's date to the message.

For e.g. I want the reminder to say:
"Hey guys, this thread is for daily stand up meeting of *today's date*. Please provide your inputs"

I dont find a way in Slack documentation to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I am looking for same answer

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can Use blocks, specifically the datepicker to receive user input then parse the response and fetch the date. After you have the date you can now use the `reminders.add` method to create the reminder.

Comment: I am not using the slack APIs, am referring to the slack app. Is there a way to customize it there